# NameError occurs after switching from vendored gems to Bundler in Rails 2.3.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler

/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@evokat25/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:105:in `const_missing':NameError: uninitialized constant Rails::Initializer::Paperclip

There is no mention of Rails::Initializer::Paperclip anywhere in my code base. Anybody have a clue as to what it is trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. I had some configuration lines in config/initializers/*.rb and config/environments/*.rb. After I put the "require" lines in each for the appropriate gems, the problem disappeared.